# How do you reference a particular AWS::StateMachine in Cloudwatch Dashboard widget Template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a working Cloudwatch Dashboard widget for a Lambda functions in my Cloudformation template like,

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    ...

  MyStateMachine:
    Type: "AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine"
    ...

  MyDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
      DashboardName: MyDashboard
      DashboardBody:
        Fn::Sub: '{
          "widgets": [
              {
                  "type": "metric",
                  "x": 0,
                  "y": 3,
                  "width": 24,
                  "height": 3,
                  "properties": {
                      "view": "singleValue",
                      "metrics": [
                          [ "AWS/Lambda", "Invocations", "FunctionName", "${MyLambda}", { "stat": "Sum", "period": 86400 } ],
                          [ ".", "Duration", ".", ".", { "stat": "Average", "period": 86400, "color": "#2ca02c" } ],
                          [ ".", "Errors", ".", ".", { "stat": "Sum", "period": 86400, "color": "#d62728" } ],
                          [ ".", "Throttles", ".", ".", { "stat": "Sum", "period": 86400, "color": "#ff7f0e" } ]
                      ],
                      "region": "us-west-2",
                      "title": "MyLambda", 
                      "stacked": true
                  }
              }
          ]
      }'
```

I want to add a widget for `MyStateMachine` to this dashboard, but I don't know how to write the State Machine equivalent of,

```
[ "AWS/Lambda", "Invocations", "FunctionName", "${MyLambda}", { "stat": "Sum", "period": 86400 } ]
```

I found that `AWS/Lambda` is called and [AWS Namespace](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/aws-namespaces.html) and the equivalent one is `AWS/States` and I found [all the options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/procedure-cw-metrics.html) I can use in place of `Invocations`, but I am not sure how to replace `FunctionName`. [This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CloudWatch-Dashboard-Body-Structure.html#CloudWatch-Dashboard-Properties-Metrics-Array-Format) suggests that I could use `InstanceId`, but there is limited documentation beyond that.

How do I create an AWS Cloudwatch Dashboard widget for my State Machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by making the widget in the AWS Web Console and then looking at the source it generated. The following worked for me.

```
                      "title": "MyLambda",
                    "stacked": true
                  }
+              },
+              {
+                  "type": "metric",
+                  "x": 0,
+                  "y": 9,
+                  "width": 24,
+                  "height": 3,
+                  "properties": {
+                      "view": "timeSeries",
+                      "metrics": [
+                          [ "AWS/States", "ActivitiesStarted", "ActivityArn", "${MyStateMachine}", { "stat": "Sum", "period": 86400 } ]
+                      ],
+                      "region": "us-west-2",
+                      "title": "State Machine Metrics",
+                      "period": 300
+                  }
               }
           ]
       }'
```